# Getting error in parsing json elements received as webhook alerts in python?

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a json that i receive from a webhook alert and read it using flask. I am able to read the content of only the entire json and cant read individual elements.

For example - `data['orders']['account']` causes error '500 internal server error' but using `data['orders']` reads the entire json elements within 'order'

The error in the console is

```
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:/Users/i0853/Desktop/python/webhook_test.py", line 28, in webhookrec
    print(data['orders']['account'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2021 10:54:40] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Hello Vikas
```

Here is the structure of the json received from the webhook url-:

```
{
    "command": "PLACE_ORDERS",
    "apiKey": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "orders": [
        {
            "account": "ACC_NUM",
            "group": false,
            "variety": "REGULAR",
            "validity": "DAY",
            "exchange": "NSE",
            "symbol": "NIFTY_29-APR-2021_FUT",
            "tradeType": "BUY",
            "orderType": "MARKET",
            "productType": "INTRADAY",
            "quantity": 75,
            "disclosedQuantity": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "triggerPrice": 0,
            "target": 0,
            "stoploss": 0,
            "trailingStoploss": 0,
            "amo": false
        },
        {
            "account": "ACC_NUM",
            "group": false,
            "variety": "REGULAR",
            "validity": "DAY",
            "exchange": "NSE",
            "symbol": "NIFTY_29-APR-2021_CE_14000",
            "tradeType": "SELL",
            "orderType": "LIMIT",
            "productType": "INTRADAY",
            "quantity": 75,
            "disclosedQuantity": 0,
            "price": 120.5,
            "triggerPrice": 0,
            "target": 25,
            "stoploss": 25,
            "trailingStoploss": 2,
            "amo": false
        }
    ]
}
```

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import json


app = Flask(__name__)


# Create root to easily let us know its on/working.
@app.route('/')
def root():
    return 'online test'   

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST','GET'])
def webhookrec():
    print('Hello Vikas')
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
         #request.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
         data = json.loads(request.data)
         
         print(data['orders']['account'])
       
         return data
    
    
         #return 'success ping', 200  
    else:
        abort(400)

#out1=webhookrec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=80)
    print('Hello again')
```

Comment: Look in the terminal window where you run the flask server. This will show a more detailed error message called a "stack trace". If you need help interpreting it, [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i have edited to include the console output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

This tells you the problem. It says that you are trying to use a string as the index of a list, which doesn't make any sense. Look at this line of code:

```
    print(data['orders']['account'])
```

The problem is readily apparent when you look at the shape of the data. In fact, I suggest starting with a simpler `print()` command:

```
    print(data['orders'])
```

You will see this prints out a list, so doing `data['orders']['account']` doesn't make any sense. Instead, you need to get a single order out of the list or iterate over the list of orders one at a time.

Comment: I was able to correct my silly mistake. Considering it as an array . there are 2 elements to 'orders' . to access each inner elements of each object i needed to specify the elemet number first so the correct method is  ```print(data['orders'][1]['account'])``` .. which  produces the correct output in console -     ```  Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2021 11:38:39] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Hello Vikas
ACC_NUM
Hello again ```

Comment: @vikaschauhan That works. As you may know, this still may throw an error if there are zero or 1 elements in the array. Depending on your use case, you should consider looping over the array: `for order in data['orders']:`.